# How To Keep UINavigation Top bar on all UIViews in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am building a small app and want to keep a button in the top right corner which calls a modal horizontal flip onto an "about us" page. Currently my code will load onto the page but it loses the top UI Navigation element.

My plan is to change the button function to act as a "back" button once you're on the new view. But I don't know how to make the same top bar "stick" across the entire Storyboard! I know this may be a bit confusing so I've uploaded my [project source on cloudapp](http://cl.ly/D7hq).

If you build & run the project you'll see a top right button with the label text "About". if you click this will perform the transition perfectly, but then on this new view we've totally lost the top bar. If I can provide any more information please let me know - just trying to get this working! as always thanks in advance

**edit*** just added a screen below of the top button I'm talking about :)
[image: top ui nav button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look at your code, but if your About button presents your view controller modally you are going to lose the top bar. You could manually add in a toolbar or navbar at the top of your modal About viewController or if you want the navigation bar to stay at the top without doing that you would have to Push the About view controller.

Comment: Which would you recommend as the standard "best practice"? I wasn't planning on adding another custom bar, it seems easier to just inherit the already existing UINavigation. I'll have to look into changing the  About button to react as a "back" method as well

Comment: I'm just gonna close this thread and start a new one with a more detailed question.. I'm working on the app right now and over the next few days so maybe I can solve the problem. But i appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationBar is mainteined across different views only when you set a UINavigationController that manages an ViewController. If you don't set a UINavigationController then you can put a UINavigationBar in your View through programmatically or visually editing your aboutViewController.xib in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller and set top bar to navigation bar

Comment: well see the problem is that adds a whole new navigation bar. I'm looking to keep the same consistent nav bar throughout the entire app - I think this requires some type of `pushViewController` method.